# Is there a method for me to find the name of an object within a constructor?

Tags: java, processing

I have a fairly simple Java related question. I need to somehow obtain the new object name within the constructor to add it to an array. How would I achieve this, if it's at all possible?

For help visualizing, here's what I need to happen.

```
TestExample example = new examplemain();
TestExample.element exelement = example.new element();
```

At this point, with the creation of the new button object, I have a constructor. The examplemain class has a function known as update. I need this update to run through every single object to update drawing elements associated with exelement. The most obvious way is to add it to an array, and then when example.update() is called, just run an array to update everything. Something like this WOULD achieve the effect I'm looking for, but only for exelement, which is no good.

```
element() {
TestExample.array[0]="exelement"
}
```

I found things like this.toString(), getName() or getClass(), but I couldn't find any meaningful way to apply it in the method I need. To reiterate, I need to be able to do something like `TestExample.array[0].status=1`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course, `TestExample.array[0].status=1` won't actually work, I literally just mean something that achieves the effect of exelement.status=1 with a variable, which... would also be nice to know but I'm pretty sure I can figure that one out on my own.

Comment: Objects don't have names, unless they are of some class that specifically has the concept of "having a name".   I think you are confusing the different concepts of "object" and "variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to understand what you are saying because your examples clearly don't do what you are saying.  (For instance `TestExample.array[0] = "exelement"` is just saving a string, and you can't resolve that to a variable.)

In fact, I'm pretty sure that the variables are a red herring too<sup>1</sup>.  What you actually need is something like this:

```
// Simplistic incorrect version ...
public class Element {
    private static List<Element> allElements = new ArrayList<>();

    public Element() {
        ...
        allElements.add(this);
    }

    public void update() { ... } 

    public static void updateAll() {
        for (Element e: allElements) {
            e.update();
        }
    }
}
```

The above has a couple of problems.  Firstly the use of `static` is liable to be a memory leak unless you either have a reliable way to clean out any elements that are no longer needed, or you use a reference type so that the GC can break the links.  The second issue is that your example is apparently using an `inner` class.

So using an inner class, it might look like this:

```
public class Outer {
    private List<Element> allElements = new ArrayList<>();

    public class Element {
        
        public Element() {
            ...
            allElements.add(this);
        }

        public void update() { ... } 
    }

    public void updateAll() {
        for (Element e: allElements) {
            e.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Now ... if the `Outer` instance becomes unreachable, so do any `Element` objects that are only reachable via `allElements`.

---

<sup>1 - But if the variables are critical, then I'm afraid you are out of luck.  Java doesn't provide a way to either take the address of a variable, or use reflection to lookup a local variable.  This is what @Louis Wasserman is saying in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64603875/139985).</sup>

Comment: I just need the name of the object so that I can manipulate it in other functions. In other terms, I just need to figure out to pass the name, in this case exelement, to the construct, so I can save it as a variable. That would be the easiest method for manipulation. HOWEVER, your method also can potentially work. I'll check in the morning. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Objects don't have names.  Variables do have names ... but not in a form that your code can manipulate.  It sounds like what you are trying to do is NOT POSSIBLE in Java.  The reason you are struggling to find a Java syntax that does what you want to do is that the syntax doesn't exist.  No amount of expressing the same concept in different words is going to get around that.

Comment: Alright. Looks like your method will work though. I assume this method is to add a reference to the object to an array, rather than an object name?

Comment: I'm getting warnings trying to implement List<> into my code. It's warning me about List<> not being a class. Is there a fix to that?

Comment: `List` is a standard interface.  Did you `import` it?

Comment: No, but that turned out not to be the problem. Someone on the Processing forums helped debug your code, and now it works. It just happens to be a typo on your part it seems. Thanks for the help! https://discourse.processing.org/t/need-to-obtain-object-name-in-constructor-solution-referencing/25039/9

Comment: Ah ... I see.  And I think I see the typo.  (I write too much python these days.)   But I don't understand how that would give a *"warning [] about List<> not being a class"*.

Comment: It's Processing Java, the IDE can be weird at times. You just have to know what you're looking at first.

Comment: `<quiet>` *tiptoes away* `</quiet>`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is absolutely impossible.  Not even reflection can find the name of a field still in the process of being initialized.

You must, for example, pass in a name into the constructor.